# How to check if a user hit a Firewall or Adblocker while migrating to my site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, branch

The website I work on uses a 3rd party software called Branch to help generate referral links. We have some users that are getting a warning from their uBlock Origin browser plugin.

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a user encountered this warning or not. I know that the user is not yet on my site when this warning appears but I am hoping there is some metadata that I might be able to leverage.

[image]